# Understanding CATransform3DRotate / CATransform3DMakeRotation

Tags: ios, swift, object, calayer, catransform3drotate

I'm trying to understand how to create depth perceptive to my `UIView` like this :

[image]

I've tried this code:

```
var rotationWithPerspective = CATransform3DIdentity;
rotationWithPerspective.m34 = -1.0/500.0/2/2
rotationWithPerspective = CATransform3DRotate(rotationWithPerspective, 22.5, 0, 1, 0);
preview.layer.transform = rotationWithPerspective
```

which generates perspective. Yet, it **Flips** the View for some reason.

1) How can I avoid the "flipping" after the transform?

2) Does the "perspective depth" resulting from the transform, will be the same to every given `UIView`, or it depends on the `UIView` size, etc?

**Thank YOU!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CATransform3DRotate` expects radians not degrees. You are rotating by 22.5 radians which is like 1200 degrees. That's probably why your image is inverted. You probably want to use this:

```
let radians = 22.5 * M_PI / 180
rotationWithPerspective = CATransform3DRotate(rotationWithPerspective, radians, 0, 1, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle! BTW, do you have an answer for my second question? is it "global perspective" values or it's per UIView?

Answer (score 1):

For 2)

- It's per UIView.
- In case you wanna apply to sublayers, you can use sublayerTransform. 
  E.g. preview.layer.sublayerTransform = rotationWithPerspective

You can read more about it in iOS Core Animation - Advanced Techniques by Nick Lockwood. Hope that help.

Comment: I want that book for SWIFT! It was released for Objective-C only :[